# Calligraphic letters in MathType

Tags: microsoft-office, latex, microsoft-publisher, mathtype

I am trying to typeset equations using MathType in Microsoft Publisher. I think Publisher is an important requirement for me since I am creating an A0 poster.

Is it possible to typeset calligraphic letters in MathType? I have attached examples of equations I typeset in Latex below. The "V" and "O" are calligraphic, and not Greek letters.

[image] [image]

Answer (score 1):

To answer the "I think Publisher is an important requirement for me since I am creating an A0 poster" part of your question, note that there are a number of LaTeX classes to create posters. See [this post on TeX.SE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/341/how-to-create-posters-using-latex) for suggestions. You can also just set the paper height and paper width using the `geometry` package, and design your poster "by hand" in LaTeX.

If you are using other software to create your poster, you could still typeset the equations in LaTeX, maybe with `LaTeXit`, and include them in the poster as images.

Finally, [this MathType fonts page](http://www.dessci.com/en/products/mathtype/fonts.htm) lets you preview some MathType fonts, have a look at [Euclid Math One](http://www.dessci.com/en/products/mathtype/misc/euclid_math1_plain.gif) for calligraphic letters.