# Typing mathematical I in Microsoft Word's equation editor

Tags: microsoft-word, fonts

[This](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) answer on math.stackexchange gives following different fonts:

[image]

I want to type highlighted I (in third last bullet point in above image) in Microsoft Words equation editor. I can type following different I's in word equation editor:

[image]

But I am unable to type I highlighted in first image. Is their any way / hack to type in that?

Comment: Is the font you highlighted the same as the one used by the equation editor?

Comment: As far as I know, word equation editor does not give choice for fonts and by default it uses Cambria Math font. Even if it allows, I am not able to find the highlighted I in any other font families.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1553271/type-calligraphic-letters-in-microsoft-office-equation-editor/1553456#1553456 May help - if the existing “calligraphic” character isn’t for you, you’ll need to insert and format the I within single quote characters.

Comment: Can you explain this how I can do it? I did not get "insert and format the I within single quote characters". Any link?

Comment: Seems that font given [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/336178/download-mathcal-ttf-font-file) is same as `\mathcal` in LaTeX

Comment: My bad - I thought you could do this but now that I am able to check, I see that you can’t change the font (in any case, it’s double quotation marks to let you insert plain text, not single ones as I said)